# IIS Virtual directory creates path issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I am using VS 2013 and MVC5
To host the application in IIS, i have used Properties-> Web ->Servers ->Local IIS and clicked on Create Virtual directory.
So this created a VD for "MyPortal"

But now i have a path problem.

I have an api controller in my application.
When i was using VS development server it was being accessed using the url : localhost:1553/api/menuapi  and the data was getting accessed correctly.

But once it is hosted to IIS, it stopped working.
When checked, it is trying to fetch the data from url i.e :
localhost/api/menuapi and it gives a 404 error.

But actually the api is fine and the data is accessible from the url :
localhost/MyPortal/api/menuapi

Why and how is this path problem created?
The below is how i am doing the api call :
1. In javascript file :
$http.get('/api/menuapi/' + menuid).success(function (data) {});
Please suggest if any alternatives.

Comment: try `$http.get('../api/menuapi/' + menuid).success(function (data) {});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your javascript will only works if the application is deployed on the top level of the webserver (/), as you are using an absolute url.

If your javascript is executed at the top level of your application, you could just change your url as relative:

```
$http.get('api/menuapi/' + menuid).success(function (data) {});
```

but if your javascript in a view, a better approach would be to retrieve the proper full url with:

```
@Url.Content("~/api/menuapi/")
```

like:

```
$http.get('@Url.Content("~/api/menuapi/")' + menuid).success(function (data) {});
```